# After loading configuration file, open selected tab

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a question in regards to a Java GUI I'm creating at the moment, it's an application that runs offsite backups.

When the application initially loads you are presented with this screen:
[image: loadscreen]

After loading the configuration file it fills out each field in the tabs below; at this stage it is staying on the "Run" tab after I load the configuration file, but I'd like it (after filling out each field) to bring the "Configuration" tab to the screen. 
[image: afterconfloaded]

How do I go about doing this? In the method I've written to load config after the JFileChooser window is closed, I'd imagine I'll need to add something to tell it to select the Configuration tab.

I can provide the classes if necessary.

Comment: [`JTabbedPane#setSelectedIndex(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29)

Comment: @MadProgrammer
Its a CTabFolder, is the method similar? 

`CTabFolder tabFolder = new CTabFolder(shlKcbsOffsiteBackup, SWT.BORDER);`

Comment: Next time, be sure to specify the UI library you're using. You'll want [`CTabFolder#setSelection(int)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabFolder.html#setSelection(int))

Answer (score 0):

Exposing the component, then using the method:

```
CTabFolder#setSelection(int);
```

worked fine.

Thanks @MadProgrammer and @Vulcan